# Need help in getting an access-token using Passport-azure-ad npm module and OIDCStrategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js, access-token, passport-azure-ad

I am trying to call Microsoft Graph API from my NodeJS express webapp and I am not able to fetch an access token from AAD.

I am able to successfully login as well as able to get the user's profile,(able to get the code and id_token) and next I want to fetch the access token so that I call make the Graph Api call.

Can someone please help understand how can I fetch the access token from the OIDCStrategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for the same.

```
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
        identityMetadata: configAuth.creds.identityMetadata,
        clientID: configAuth.creds.clientID, 
        responseType: configAuth.creds.responseType,
        responseMode: configAuth.creds.responseMode,
        redirectUrl: configAuth.creds.redirectUrl, 
        allowHttpForRedirectUrl: configAuth.creds.allowHttpForRedirectUrl,
        clientSecret: configAuth.creds.clientSecret,
        validateIssuer: configAuth.creds.validateIssuer,
        isB2C: configAuth.creds.isB2C,
        issuer: configAuth.creds.issuer,
        passReqToCallback: configAuth.creds.passReqToCallback, 
        scope: configAuth.creds.scope,
        loggingLevel: configAuth.creds.loggingLevel, 
        nonceLifetime: configAuth.creds.nonceLifetime,
        nonceMaxAmount: configAuth.creds.nonceMaxAmount,
        useCookieInsteadOfSession: configAuth.creds.useCookieInsteadOfSession,
        cookieEncryptionKeys: configAuth.creds.cookieEncryptionKeys,
        clockSkew: configAuth.creds.clockSkew,
    }, (req, iss, sub, profile, access_token, refresh_token, params, done) => {
        console.log(`Profile >>>> ${JSON.stringify(profile)}`);
        if(!profile.oid) {
            return done(new Error("No oid found"), null);
        }
        profile.tokens = params;
        // console.log(`Access-Token >>>> ${access_token}`);
        // console.log(`Refresh-Token >>>> ${refresh_token}`);       
        // console.log(`Profile >>>>>>>>>>>>>> ${JSON.stringify(profile)}`);
        process.nextTick(() => {
            findByOid(profile.oid, (err, user) => {
                if(err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if(!user) {
                    users.push(profile);
                    return done(null, profile);
                }
                return done(null, user);      
            });
        });
    }));
```